# Remover elemento de array em C

Tags: c, array

tenho a seguinte struct.

```
struct cadastro{
int codigo;
char nome[200];
char cpf[11];
char rg[10];
char tel[12];
char end[100];

}cadastro;//struct do tipo cadastro.
```

e o vetor correspondente

```
struct cadastro cd[10];//vetor da funcao cadastro de cliente
```

meu programa é um mini terminal de vendas, eu quero então, em um dado momento, quero informar uma posição (indice do vetor) e quero excluir ( ou seja, jogar os itens do indice da frente, -1.

```
//ex: vou apagar vetor na posição 3, oque está na posição 4° == 3°, oque está na posição 4° = 5°, até o final do meu vetor.
```

oque não consigo pensar é na forma de implementar isso.

tentei o seguinte

```
for(cod; cod < 10; cod++)
{
  cd[cod] = cd[cod+1];
}
```

pelo menos essa ideia. mas não aconteceu do jeito que eu queria e o programa interrompe e volta ao menu;

Comment: Dê mais detalhes, só isto não nos ajuda te ajudar.

Comment: Ok, imagine um terminal de vendas. Voce quer remover um cliente, ou até mesmo um produto, vc "lista" com um laço os itens e na frente vc (indexa) com a variavel do laço for, e exibe todos produtos cadastrados, blz, ai exibo uma mensagem pra vc, quer excluir algum item/cliente? digite o indice, ai você vai digita o indice, e apartir do numero digitado ele começa a "mover os dados i+1, para o i" literalmente movendo 1 pra traz e sobrescrevendo aquele indice do vetor que o usuario especificou, minha ideia eh essa. :)

Comment: Isso tudo já está na pergunta. Isto é abstrato. Isto pouco importa para ajudarmos você, a não ser que façamos tudo para você, o que não é o objetivo do site. Coloque na pergunta coisas concretas do que está fazendo, como está seu código. Qual seu problema, etc.

Comment: Já tentou isso: `for( i = posicao; i < 10 - 1; i++) { c[ i ] = c[ i + 1 ] };` ?

Comment: Lacobus, foi meu pensamento.
bigown, desculpe se ainda não consigo expressar corretamente toda minha necessidade atravez dos meus codigos e linha de pensamento, "pra mim" ainda é bastante coisa, e todo o codigo está afrente do que eu sei (sei pouquissima coisa), e oq acontece, é justamente oq você comentou, nao é o intuito do site, vocês me entregarem o codigo ponto, mesmo por que eu não aprenderia absolutamente nada e, no dia da avaliação vou pensar, poxa tive o codigo feito não pensei em nada, não vai me salvar, não vou ter o site para perguntar na prova.

Answer (score 2):

Pense em como vc faria se fosse uma série de objetos reais.

Imagine 10 moedas em fila na mesa. Vc retira uma quer relocar as outras pro lugar dela.
Vc não começa do início da fila né ? vc começa da posição que foi removida e vai colocando uma a uma. A 1a é a à direita da posição da que saiu e será colocada na posição da que saiu, a próxima pro lugar desta, etc.

Então vc tem que ter uma variável com a posição do elemento a ser retirado. 
Tem uma instrução para obter um indíce do usuário e colocar numa variável. Procure descobrir qual é.

Após isso tem que fazer um for até o final da lista movendo todos os outros objetos para a sua posição -1.

Veja se essa descrição lhe auxilia.

**Edição respondendo ao cometário do autor da pergunta**

Após apagar um dos elementos, vc tem 2 opções:

- vc pode criar um novo array menor e copiar tudo pra lá. Mais ou menos 
  assim:

código:

```
struct cadastro2 cd[9];
for(int i=0;i<9;i++) cadastro2[i]=cadastro[i];
delete(array);
cadastro=cadastro2;
```

digo mais ou menos pq vc tem que adaptar isso ao for que diminui o array.

- ou vc pode simplesmente trabalhar com o array sem diminuir a cada elemento e apenas apagar o array no final.

Caso opte pela 2a opção claro que algum espaço na memória será alocado sem uso. Mas não ocorre qualquer leak de memória. Apenas o desperdício de alguns bytes. Portanto no seu caso esse espaço é irrisório e esse tipo de preciosismo ocupa tempo demais seu (tempo custoso para uma empresa). Então se preocupe em otimizar nesse nível apenas quando realmente valer a pena. 
Acredite em mim. Quando vc estiver desenvolvendo "pra valer" irão haver oportunidades de sobra pra vc desenvolver seus talentos de otimização e controle de leaks :)

Comment: eh basicamente essa minha ideia, eu ja peço pro usuario, qual posição q ele quer começar, digo no vetor, pra ele startar daquela posição em diante, e então ele vem recuando sempre -1, no caso me preocupo"nao sei se tem necessidade" com a ultima posição se vai ficar vazia ou lixo de memoria

Answer (score 1):

Segue a solução completa do cadastro de clientes usando vetor estático:

```
/*
    cadastro.c
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define ERRO_CADASTRO_CHEIO           (-2)
#define ERRO_CLIENTE_NAO_ENCONTRADO   (-1)
#define SUCESSO                       (0)

#define CLIENTES_MAX_QTD              (10)


typedef struct cliente_s cliente_t;
typedef struct cadastro_s cadastro_t;


struct cliente_s
{
    int codigo;
    char nome[100];
    char cpf[16];
    char rg[16];
    char tel[32];
    char end[200];
};


struct cadastro_s
{
    cliente_t cliente[ CLIENTES_MAX_QTD ];
    int qtd;
};


void cadastro_inicializar( cadastro_t * cad )
{
    memset( cad, 0, sizeof(cadastro_t) );
}


int cadastro_incluir_cliente( cadastro_t * cad, int cod, const char * nome, const char * cpf, const char * rg, const char * tel, const char * end )
{
    if( cad->qtd == CLIENTES_MAX_QTD )
        return ERRO_CADASTRO_CHEIO;

    cad->cliente[ cad->qtd ].codigo = cod;
    strcpy( cad->cliente[ cad->qtd ].nome, nome );
    strcpy( cad->cliente[ cad->qtd ].cpf, cpf );
    strcpy( cad->cliente[ cad->qtd ].rg, rg );
    strcpy( cad->cliente[ cad->qtd ].tel, tel );
    strcpy( cad->cliente[ cad->qtd ].end, end );

    cad->qtd++;

    return SUCESSO;
}


int cadastro_remover_cliente( cadastro_t * cad, int cod )
{
    int i, j;

    /* Para cada cliente cadastrado... */
    for( i = 0; i < cad->qtd; i++ )
    {
        /* Verifica se o cliente possui o codigo desejado */ 
        if( cad->cliente[i].codigo == cod )
        {
            /* Ajusta vetor: Desloca todos os clientes uma posicao */ 
            for( j = i; j < cad->qtd - 1; j++ )
                cad->cliente[ j ] = cad->cliente[ j + 1 ];

            /* Decrementa contador de clientes */
            cad->qtd--;

            return SUCESSO;
        }
    }

    return ERRO_CLIENTE_NAO_ENCONTRADO;
}


void cadastro_listar_clientes( cadastro_t * cad )
{
    int i = 0;

    printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("| Codigo |          Nome        |     CPF     |    RG    |  Telefone  |              Endereco          |\n");
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

    for( i = 0; i < cad->qtd; i++ )
        printf("|  %4d  | %-20s | %-11s | %s | %-10s | %-30s |\n", cad->cliente[i].codigo, cad->cliente[i].nome, cad->cliente[i].cpf, cad->cliente[i].rg, cad->cliente[i].tel, cad->cliente[i].end );

    printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    cadastro_t cad;

    /* Inicializa cadastro de clientes */
    cadastro_inicializar( &cad );

    /* Faz o cadastro de 10 clientes */
    cadastro_incluir_cliente( &cad,  10, "Albert Einstein",   "60742061477", "1234/SSP", "3234-5678", "Avenida Foobar, S/N" );
    cadastro_incluir_cliente( &cad,  20, "Isaac Newton",      "70344162907", "9898/SSP", "1234-5678", "Rua XPTO, Num. 31415" );
    cadastro_incluir_cliente( &cad,  30, "Stephen Hawking",   "78450688701", "4323/SSP", "5678-9989", "Praca Vinte, Num. 34" );
    cadastro_incluir_cliente( &cad,  40, "Leonardo da Vinci", "66814865173", "3456/SSP", "9989-1111", "Avenida Trinta, Num. 54" );
    cadastro_incluir_cliente( &cad,  50, "Galileu Galilei",   "15487316252", "9809/SSP", "9781-5555", "Rua Noventa e Tres, S/N" );
    cadastro_incluir_cliente( &cad,  60, "Ada Lovelace",      "13747920632", "1212/SSP", "9871-4532", "Rua dos Moradores, no. 100" );
    cadastro_incluir_cliente( &cad,  70, "Marie Curie",       "41325527300", "4545/SSP", "3456-1234", "Avenida da Cidade, Nem. 32" );
    cadastro_incluir_cliente( &cad,  80, "Nikola Tesla",      "12312312300", "6565/SSP", "8765-3456", "Rua Sem Nome, S/N" );
    cadastro_incluir_cliente( &cad,  90, "Michael Faraday",   "99988877700", "4444/SSP", "2323-3214", "Vila da Travessa, 123" );
    cadastro_incluir_cliente( &cad, 100, "Johannes Kepler",   "32132132111", "4343/SSP", "9898-4545", "Avenida Vazia, Numero 0" );

    /* Lista clientes cadastrados (antes das exclusoes) */
    cadastro_listar_clientes( &cad );

    /* Exclui clientes do cadastro */
    cadastro_remover_cliente( &cad, 60 );
    cadastro_remover_cliente( &cad, 70 );

    /* Lista clientes cadastrados (apos exclusoes) */
    cadastro_listar_clientes( &cad );

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

Porém, uma melhor maneira de resolver seu problema seria implementar uma lista encadeada ao invés de usar um vetor estático.

Segue um exemplo seguindo o seu raciocínio:

```
/*
    cadastro-lista-encadeada.c
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct cadastro_s cadastro_t;

struct cadastro_s
{
    int codigo;
    char nome[100];
    char cpf[16];
    char rg[16];
    char tel[32];
    char end[200];

    cadastro_t * prox;
};


cadastro_t * cadastro_criar( int cod, char * nome, char * cpf, char * rg, char * tel, char * end )
{
    cadastro_t * c = malloc(sizeof(cadastro_t));

    c->codigo = cod;
    strcpy( c->nome, nome );
    strcpy( c->cpf, cpf );
    strcpy( c->rg, rg );
    strcpy( c->tel, tel );
    strcpy( c->end, end );

    c->prox = NULL;

    return c;
}


void cadastro_incluir( cadastro_t ** c, cadastro_t * item )
{
    cadastro_t * p = *c;

    if( !p )
    {
        item->prox = NULL;
        *c = item;
        return;
    }

    while( p->prox )
        p = p->prox;

    item->prox = NULL;
    p->prox = item;
}


int cadastro_remover( cadastro_t ** c, int cod )
{
    cadastro_t * p = *c;
    cadastro_t * pant = NULL;

    while( p )
    {
        if( p->codigo == cod )
        {
            if( pant )
            {
                pant->prox = p->prox;
            }
            else
            {
                *c = p->prox;
            }

            free(p);

            return 0;
        }

        pant = p;
        p = p->prox;
    }

    return -1;
}


void cadastro_destruir( cadastro_t * c )
{
    cadastro_t * paux = NULL;
    cadastro_t * p = c;

    while( p )
    {
        paux = p->prox;
        free(p);
        p = paux;
    }
}


void cadastro_listar( cadastro_t * c )
{
    cadastro_t * p = NULL;

    printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("| Codigo |          Nome        |     CPF     |    RG    |  Telefone  |              Endereco          |\n");
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

    for( p = c; p != NULL; p = p->prox )
    {
        printf("|  %4d  | %-20s | %-11s | %s | %-10s | %-30s |\n", p->codigo, p->nome, p->cpf, p->rg, p->tel, p->end );
    }

    printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    cadastro_t * c = NULL;

    /* Populando lista com 10 cadastros */
    cadastro_incluir( &c, cadastro_criar(  10, "Albert Einstein",   "60742061477", "1234/SSP", "3234-5678", "Avenida Foobar, S/N" ) );
    cadastro_incluir( &c, cadastro_criar(  20, "Isaac Newton",      "70344162907", "9898/SSP", "1234-5678", "Rua XPTO, Num. 31415" ) );
    cadastro_incluir( &c, cadastro_criar(  30, "Stephen Hawking",   "78450688701", "4323/SSP", "5678-9989", "Praca Vinte, Num. 34" ) );
    cadastro_incluir( &c, cadastro_criar(  40, "Leonardo da Vinci", "66814865173", "3456/SSP", "9989-1111", "Avenida Trinta, Num. 54" ) );
    cadastro_incluir( &c, cadastro_criar(  50, "Galileu Galilei",   "15487316252", "9809/SSP", "9781-5555", "Rua Noventa e Tres, S/N" ) );
    cadastro_incluir( &c, cadastro_criar(  60, "Ada Lovelace",      "13747920632", "1212/SSP", "9871-4532", "Rua dos Moradores, no. 100" ) );
    cadastro_incluir( &c, cadastro_criar(  70, "Marie Curie",       "41325527300", "4545/SSP", "3456-1234", "Avenida da Cidade, Nem. 32" ) );
    cadastro_incluir( &c, cadastro_criar(  80, "Nikola Tesla",      "12312312300", "6565/SSP", "8765-3456", "Rua Sem Nome, S/N" ) );
    cadastro_incluir( &c, cadastro_criar(  90, "Michael Faraday",   "99988877700", "4444/SSP", "2323-3214", "Vila da Travessa, 123" ) );
    cadastro_incluir( &c, cadastro_criar( 100, "Johannes Kepler",   "32132132111", "4343/SSP", "9898-4545", "Avenida Vazia, Numero 0" ) );

    /* Lista itens cadastrados (antes das exclusoes) */
    cadastro_listar( c );

    /* Exclui itens do cadastro */
    cadastro_remover( &c, 60 );
    cadastro_remover( &c, 70 );

    /* Lista itens cadastrados (apos exclusoes) */
    cadastro_listar( c );

    /* Libera memoria ocupada pelo cadastro */
    cadastro_destruir( c );

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

Espero que ajude!

Comment: opa Lacobus, tudo bom? então ainda não aprendi lista, malemal aprendemos pilha, mas muito obrigado pela sua ajuda com o codigo, é mais mesmo uma ideia de vetorização, onde eu indico o indice do vetor, e trago o elemento da frente no lugar do que foi excluido.

Comment: @MarcioHenrique Pronto! Editei a resposta e inclui uma solução usando um vetor estático.

Comment: Uau Lacobus, que codigo massa to lendo, pelo pouco de exp que tenho em progrramação, e vendo sua forma de programação, to :-o